# Sorting out in order a Convert to string Datetime in SQL Server and Crystal Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

```
    SELECT  t_PONumber,
            t_Date,
            t_VendorID,
            t_VendName,
            t_Itemnmbr,
            t_ItemDesc,
            t_UnitCost,
            case when t_QtyOrder = 0 then (Select QtyOrder from POP10110 where PONUMBER =t_PONUMBER and Ord=t_Ord) ELSE t_QtyOrder END AS t_QtyOrder,
            t_QtyRecv,
            t_QtyCancel,
            t_DocNum,
            t_DRorSI,
  --->      case when convert(nvarchar(21),t_RRDate)='Jan  1 1900 12:00AM' then '' else convert(nvarchar(21),t_RRDate) end AS t_RRDate,
            t_DocType,
            t_Ord 
    FROM @SupplierPOMonitoring
    ORDER BY t_Date, t_RRDate--, t_PONumber,t_Ord,t_Itemnmbr
```

I've Converted the smalldatetime format to a 'Jan 02 1900' Format style and when i tried to order it its not picking it up on my crystal report its showing although its sort like

'Oct 1'

'Oct 2'

'Oct 5'

'Oct 10'

'Sept 4'

'Sept 7'

'Sept 12'

'Sept 18'

Can i sort also the month of it. how do i do that in sql or in Crystal Report if i don't use a convert date it sorted out but if i do its not taking the month but the days are sort.

Actual View on Report:

[image]

Comment: absolutely correct sorting, O is before S, so Oct is before Sep, remove any sorting from crystal reporting, you already have proper sorting in sql query

Comment: i want it to be sort as monthly like september then october then november.. how can i do that sir using a string on mssql?

Comment: you mean that you field is not `date` type, but `string` one? then you should revert it and sort via date field like it is already in query

Comment: if i have a date in string taking just the month Oct,Jan,Dec,Sept,Nov how do i sort it like this -> Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan using order by would be sorting it by letters not by month just like the calendar is there a way to sort it by string not by datetime format?

Comment: I don't understand you, `date` type will be sorted correctly, then you probably will need to apply date format to this column on crystal's side, or you can use date format functions from ms sql, but for sure - you have to store dates in field with `date` type and sort via this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert to a string in SQL Server. Instead have Crystal do the formatting. That way it can sort based on the date and not on the string value.

So, instead of

```
case when convert(nvarchar(21),t_RRDate)='Jan  1 1900 12:00AM' then '' else convert(nvarchar(21),t_RRDate) end AS t_RRDate
```

use

```
NULLIF(t_RRDate,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS t_RRDate
```

In crystal you then can apply date formatting rules and blank out NULLs.

You can use Crystal Report's `ToText` function for this:

```
ToText({datefield},”MMM dd”)
```

Comment: yes sir that's how i solved the problem i stop converting it and let crystal report do the format thanks sir for answering my question and the NULLIF(t_RRDate,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS t_RRDate work very ok in taking out the null value. can u take out the -1 in my post? :(

Answer (score 0):

As Ilya was saying, you need to remove your conversion form the SQL statement so it can be sorted correctly by date (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 for the months) in Crystal. If you convert it to string in SQL it will sort alphabetically by month name (January, February, etc.). Do the conversion using a formula in Crystal so you can sort by date but show the month name.

Cheers,

Chris